# How to get network information from metrics server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-metrics

I know how to get information(limit, request, usage) of cpu and memory from metrics-server.

But I don't know how to get network information(Memory Distribution, Network Traffic(KBps), Network Utilization) from metrics-server.

Essentially, metrics-server don't provide network information?
Is there another way?

I should develop with python.

Answer (score 0):

Metrics server does not export these kind of metrics but Prometheus Node Exporter does.  Node exporter run as a systemd service that will periodically (every 1 second) gather all the metrics of your system.

> The Prometheus [**Node
> Exporter**](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) exposes a
> wide variety of hardware- and kernel-related metrics.

You can check all the list of the collectors [here](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter). You may also want to check this article about monitoring network with prometheus.